# how to push array object to array object javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

How to push the object into array of property value matches in javascript.

I have objects `obj1` and `obj2`, in which if property `name` matches

then push the prop of object `obj2`, how to implement in javascript

```
function arrayobj(obj1, obj2){
  var obj = obj2.map(e=>({
          info: {
            id: e.id,
            qty: e.qty
          }
         }));
}

var obj1 = [
 {
  idx:1,
  name: "sample1"
 },
 {
  idx:2,
  name: "sample2"
 }
]

var obj2=[
  {
    id:1,
    name: "sample1",
    qty: 10
  },
  {
    id:3,
    name: "sample1",
    qty: 30
  },
  {
    id:2,
    name: "sample2",
    qty: 20
  }
]
```

Expected Output:

```
[
 {
  idx:1,
  name: "sample1",
  info: [
    {id:1, qty:10},
    {id:3, qty:30}
  ]
 },
 {
  idx:2,
  name: "sample2",
  info: [
   {id:2, qty:20}
  ]
 }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(o1 of obj1)
  for(o2 of obj2)
    if(o1.name==o2.name) {
      if(!o1.info) o1.info=[];
      o1.info.push({id:o2.id, qty:o2.qty});
    }
```

To see what  we've got, use:

```
JSON.stringify(obj1,null,"  ")
```

```
[
  {
    "idx": 1,
    "name": "sample1",
    "info": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "qty": 10
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "qty": 30
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "idx": 2,
    "name": "sample2",
    "info": [
      {
        "id": 2,
        "qty": 20
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: If you like my answer, please up-vote it, and
If you think it's the best, please select it.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `map` and `filter` feature of the array to get expected result.

```js
var obj1 = [
  {
    idx: 1,
    name: "sample1"
  },
  {
    idx: 2,
    name: "sample2"
  }
]

var obj2 = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "sample1",
    qty: 10
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: "sample1",
    qty: 30
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "sample2",
    qty: 20
  }
]

const finalArray = obj1.map(obj1Item => {
  return {
    ...obj1Item,
    info: obj2
      .filter(obj2Item => obj2Item.name === obj1Item.name)
      .map(obj2Item => ({ id: obj2Item.id, qty: obj2Item.qty }))
  }
})

console.log(finalArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert the array to object to avoid the inner loop.

```js
function arrayobj(obj1, obj2){

  // converting obj2 to object
  // with key-> name and value-> array of object{id, qty}
  const objFromArray = obj2.reduce((acc, item) => {
    if(!acc[item.name]) {
      acc[item.name] = [];
    }
    acc[item.name].push({
      id: item.id,
      qty: item.qty
    });
    return acc;
  }, {});

  // now iterate over the obj1
  const result = obj1.map(item => {
    return {
      ...item,
      info: objFromArray[item.name] 
    }
  });
  return result;
}


var obj1 = [
 {
  idx:1,
  name: "sample1"
 },
 {
  idx:2,
  name: "sample2"
 }
]

var obj2=[
  {
    id:1,
    name: "sample1",
    qty: 10
  },
  {
    id:3,
    name: "sample1",
    qty: 30
  },
  {
    id:2,
    name: "sample2",
    qty: 20
  }
]


console.log(arrayobj(obj1, obj2));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:

```
const combineObjects = (obj1, obj2) => {
    const obj = [];
    obj1.forEach(({idx, name}) => {
        const info = obj2.filter(el2 => name === el2.name);
        info.forEach(el => delete el.name);
        obj.push( {
            idx,
            name,
            info
        } );
    });
    return obj;
};

console.log(combineObjects(obj1, obj2));
```